Finding the minimum through a chain of inequalities
Assume I have a convex function $f$ over positive-valued numbers. For each $x$, we have $f(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. How can I prove, using a chain of inequalities, that for each $x, f(x) \geq f(1)$, meaning that the minimum occurs at $x=1$ ?
I can only think of the following
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{2}(f(x) + f(x)) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(f(x) + f(1/x)) \\
&\geq f\left(\frac{1}{2}(x + 1/x)\right).
\end{align}

Let $x_{n+1}=\frac12(x_n+\frac1{x_n})$ for $n\ge 1$, where $x_1=x>1$. From the AM-GM inequality, we have $x_n>1$ for all $n\ge 1$. Also,
$$
x_{n+1}-1 = \frac12(x_n + \frac1{x_n}-2) < \frac12(x_n-1).
$$
Therefore, $x_n \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.
Now, as the OP showed in the post, we have $f(x_n)\ge f(x_{n+1})$ for all $n\ge 1$. (This is a chain of inequalities.) Taking the limit $n\to\infty$ gives $f(x)\ge f(1)$ as desired.

+1. Nice answer.

Definition of convexity seems to work.
For any $x > 1$, $\alpha \in [0,1]$,
\begin{align*}
f(x) \ge  f( \alpha x + (1 - \alpha) \frac{1}{x})
\end{align*}
Fix any $x > 1$, then the term $\frac{1 - \frac{1}{x}}{x - \frac{1}{x} } \in (0,1)$, so we can set this term to $\alpha$, and on substituting in the original equation, you shall get $f(x) \ge f(1)$ for any $x \ge 1$. And since $f(x) = f(\frac{1}{x})$, we are done.

Since $f$ is convex, for all $r>0,$ we have:
$$ f(1)= f\left( \left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right) r + \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+r} \right)\frac{1}{r} \right)\leq \frac{1}{1+r} f(r) + \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+r} \right)f\left(\frac{1}{r}\right) $$
$$ = \frac{1}{1+r} f(r) + \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+r} \right)f(r) = f(r),$$
where in the penultimate step we used the fact that $f(r) = f\left(\frac{1}{r}\right). $
